# Java 8 BasicFileAttributes.creationTime() returning different hour value

Tags: java, java-8

I have this code snippet using Java 8 to get the Creation Date Time of a specific file:

```
    Path path = Paths.get("D:\\SampleFile.txt");
    BasicFileAttributes attributes = null;
    try {
        attributes = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class);
        System.out.println("Creation Date Time: " + attributes.creationTime());
    } catch(IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The real creation hour of the file I am using as an example differs by 6 hours from the one the above code snippet displays: 
Real date time: 2017-02-05T**10**:34:28 
This code time: 2017-02-05T**16**:34:28.247156Z

Does anybody know what is the reason of this difference and how to get the correct create date time value ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Probably a time zone issue.

Comment: Definitely a time zone issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `FileTime` class assumes UTC as the default time zone for printing. If you want to print it in your system's time zone, you can convert it to a `ZonedDateTime` like this:

```
attributes.creationTime().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved my question completely!

Answer (score 1):

As per [`FileTime.toString()` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/FileTime.html#toString--) the value is always presented as UTC time zone: Hence the "Z" at the end.

Answer (score -1):

As per [Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html) says:

If the file system implementation does not support a time stamp to indicate the time when the file was created then this method returns an implementation specific default value, typically the last-modified-time or a FileTime representing the epoch (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z).

your file system implementation could doesn't support this, I think this is the last modified date.